# Вопрос по сворачиванию окна в pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, rollup

Я убрал в своём коде всё заднее окно.(кнопку закрыть и т.п.) Я также добавил кнопку, по нажатию которой у меня закрывается программа. Теперь мне нужно сделать кнопку, которая будет сворачивать программу. Подскажите, какой код использовать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599334/minimizing-a-qt-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setWindowState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowState)

```
win.setWindowState(win.windowState() | Qt.WindowMinimized)
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метод [showMinimized](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMinimized):

```
self.showMinimized()
```